# Proving (by using Zorn's lemma) that every nonempty set contains a maximal ideal

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, ideals

I am trying to prove the following exercise:

Let $X \neq \emptyset$. Prove, (by using Zorn's Lemma) that there exists a maximal ideal in $P(X)$.

Proof: Take $\mathcal{J}$ to be the set of all ideals that can be defined on $X$. Note that $\mathcal{J} \neq \emptyset$, since $\{ \emptyset \}$ is an ideal. $\mathcal{J}$, is partially ordered by inclusion. given a chain $\{J_i\}$ of ideals in $\mathcal{J}$, $J=\bigcup_{i \in I}J_i$, is an ideal in $\mathcal{J}$, So, every chain in $\mathcal{J}$, has an upper bound in $\mathcal{J}$. By Zorn's Lemma, we get that there exists a maximal element in $\mathcal{J}$, and this element is a maximal ideal in $X$.

What do you think?

Thank you!
Shir

Comment: Looks good, but it lacks a proof for the statement that the union of a chain of ideals is an ideal. Not that it is hard or very deep, but it needs to be done.

Comment: Ok, will be added. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a detail: you want to say that $\mathcal{J}$ is the set of *proper* ideals; then you need to check that the union of a chain of proper ideals is a proper ideal.

This is not difficult, because there's a simple characterization of proper ideals, as those that don't contain …

Note: in the the set of all ideals there exist a greatest element, namely $P(X)$, and you don't want it.

Comment: Yes.. you are right.. Thank you!